# How to make a HTML code that automatically uploads a file to a upload form

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, python-3.x

I am trying to develop an android app using a website (website is the target). I want to make a file automatically upload from SDcard to that html form. What to do now?? I want to remove the choose file button and make the desired file to be automatically uploaded

**MY Code:-**

```html
<div style="background-color:#ffffff; padding:1px 10px">
<p><font size="+0">Example program</font></p>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="www.google.com" method="POST">
    <strong><p>Upload "the file": <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="gkey"/>
 <br>or</br>
    Enter Code: <input type="text" size="42" name="encoded"/><input type="submit" value="Send"/></p>
  </form>
 </strong>
<p/>
<font color="999999">Test value:<br/></font>
<font color="999999" face="monospace">##test value##</font>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in JS as the user *has* to choose the file to be uploaded for security reasons.Just imagine if this was possible, I could have access to any file on your machine when you visit my website without you ever knowing

Comment: I think that in this case what the SO wants is that this app installed in the phone post a file in a specific route to this website. Is the app the one with access to the filesystem, not the website. The app should encapsulate this website and overwrite the target form, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that due to security reasons. If you find out how to do that anyway, feel free to file bug/security report to browser's manufacturer and get a bounty...